# bind_rows repeating outputs

Tags: dataframe, tidyverse

I'm trying to extract data from xls-files, which have always the same structure (see below). After extracting the ranges of interest with:

```
all_data            <- (file.path(wdir, 'data_input.xlsx'))
excel_sheets(path = all_results)
tab_names           <- excel_sheets(path = all_results)

extracted_data      <- lapply(tab_names, function(x) read_excel(all_data, 
                                                                sheet = x, col_names=FALSE, range = "B2:B4"))
```

I would like to bring everything into a wide format. Yet, when I use:

```
extracted_data_wide <- extracted_data %>% bind_rows(extracted_data, .id=NULL)
```

it seems to repeat all inputs once, which is not plausible for me. Is there anyone who can help me understand where the problem is or who could probably offer a different solution for my question? I had also thought on `pivot_wider` but it doesn't work with the output extracted_data the way I thought.

**Example data:**
[image: exemplary data arrangement in xls-file called data_input.xlsx]

Comment: Could you please clarify what your expected result should look like? As you want a wide format perhaps you are looking for `bind_cols`?

Comment: That's a great start and it actually shows the problem I am facing. If I use `bind_cols` my output still shows the results twice (it repeats the extracted dataframe) and I don't understand why this happens. I want to have a dataframe with two columns (c('foo1', 'foo2')) and as many rows as there are sheets (4 worksheets in this case, although in my more complex scenario there are hundreds of worksheets). I don't understand where the problem with my code is, so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not really sure about your desired result, but I give it a try

1. As you want two columns `foo1` and `foo2` I would guess that you want to extract only the first two rows of your data.
2. Instead of just getting the values in column B of your excel sheets extract the names in column A too, using `range="A2:B3"`.
3. Afterwards use bind_rows. One issue with your code was that you passed the list of dataframe two times to `bind_rows`.
4. When using `bind_rows` add an `.id` for the sheets
5. Besides renaming you could then use `pivot_wider` to convert your data to wide format with rows corresponding to sheets and columns corresponding to the rows of your excel sheets

```r
# Make example data
all_results <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")

d1 <- data.frame(
  name = paste0("foo", 1:10),
  value = paste0("bar", 1:10)
)

d2 <- data.frame(
  name = paste0("foo", 1:10),
  value = paste0("bar", 11:20)
)

writexl::write_xlsx(list(d1, d2), path = all_results)

library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tab_names <- excel_sheets(path = all_results)
extracted_data <- lapply(tab_names, function(x) read_excel(all_results, sheet = x, col_names=FALSE, range = "A2:B3"))
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> * `` -> ...2
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> * `` -> ...2

extracted_data_wide <- extracted_data %>% bind_rows(.id = "sheet")

extracted_data_wide %>% 
  rename(foo = 2, value = 3) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = foo, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   sheet foo1  foo2 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 1     bar1  bar2 
#> 2 2     bar11 bar12
```

Comment: Stefan, this is great and very intuitive especially on the second part. Thank you very much! I cannot explain the first part of the question any better because I cannot frame it in a MWE. When I call `extracted_data_wide <- extracted_data %>% bind_rows(.id = "sheet")` with my data, I get a tibble with twice as many rows as I have sheets (1:n,1:n). It's not a major issue because I can just skip the second part of the dataframe, but I can't understand why this happens. But let's not overengineer stuff at this point, you helped me a lot.